# dynamic schema evaluation on a dataframe column is running long

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am sending a join query from databricks to postgresql using spark jdbc. the resultant row count is 170k records. I have a column named "data" in the result dataframe. This contains a json string whose structure may or may not be same for all rows. so since the schema of the "column" is not static, I am not defining any structure upfront. I am using the following to derive the schema dynamically.

```
 json_schema = spark.read.json(df_code.select("data").rdd.map(lambda row: row.data)).schema
 df_json_data = df_code.withColumn('json_data', F.from_json(F.col('data'), json_schema)).drop('data')
```

This is exactly how I am converting the string representation of json to json column.
But it is taking a lot of time. If it is handful of records, say few thousands, there is no issue. But in this case, I have 170k records and the job doesn't seem to progress.

I am using a cluster with 4 workers and 1 driver. Each Worker has 56 GB memory and 8 cores.
Although it is a shared cluster, No notebooks are running on this cluster while I am running the job. I am unable to figure out how to solve the issue. Any inputs to resolve this is highly appreciated. Requesting help from the community.

**sample data:**

Please note that in the sample data, I have mentioned **867506 Random Characters and 116 Random Characters** in the first record. I think our source webpage is capturing the jpg images and its relevant text is captured in our postgresql. These random characters has alphanumeric with special characters as well. image for reference is below. Larger the jpg file size, greater the character length will be I guess in this json. As I mentioned this "data" column doesn't have a proper structure. That's why you see different schema for each record.

**Record1:**
{"recomend_portal":2,
"upload":[{"storage":"base64","name":"dbeaver.exe"
,"url":"data:application/x-msdownload;base64,867506 Random Characters","size":532488,"type":"application/x-msdownload","originalName":"dbeaver.exe","hash":"0fbee5a6f48b20225eb23bb59d870147","fileType":"JPG"}]
,"secondUploadPdf":[{"storage":"base64","name":"My HR Tool-94a42a23-6239-42ca-b5d6-ea13c5969b24.url","url":"data:application/octet-stream;base64,116 Random Characters",
"size":86,"type":null,"originalName":"My HR Tool.url","hash":"0fbee5a6f48b20225eb23bb59d870147","fileType":"PDF"}],
"aFieldWithInlineValidation":"df","thePortalsCapabilitiesMetMyNeeds":4}

**Record2:**
{"recomend_portal":0,"thePortalsCapabilitiesMetMyNeeds":8,"upload":[],"secondUploadPdf":[]}

**Record3:**
{"start_time":"2023-06-28 16:00:00","end_time":"2023-06-28 17:00:00"}

[image]

Comment: Yes I am using azure Databricks.

Comment: I thought the data is not evenly distributed.I used numPartitions=500 in jdbc call. Yet there is no improvement. getNumPartition() shows only 1 partition even after using 500 partitions. If I explicitly repartition it, the repartition is also taking a lot of time.  Only a single task is created in the stage.

Comment: provide sample rows of your column `data`.

Comment: @JayashankarGS: Edited the post. Added Sample data in the Question section. Kindly review.

Comment: run `json_schema = spark.read.json(df_code.select("data").rdd.map(lambda row: row.data)).schema` in separate cell and check whether you are getting schema or not.

Comment: @JayashankarGS: I tried to run it in separate cell. But, no luck. It is executing since past 1 hour and no progress. When I look in the sparkUI, only one task is created.

Answer (score 0):

Had a word with source team to understand the need to have the jpg image inside the json column. They mentioned that the initial version of their code was writing the image into the database, the latest version is only saving the image's storage location on blob into the json column. The code runs fine with the data that doesn't have the image directly stored in json. But I still do not understand why the job doesn't run when the image is stored in a table. But for now, my problem is solved since we are going to a new version.

Comment: What is the average size of images of 170k records. If you take average size of 5mb then for 170k records the size of the data will be more than 500gb. You need more time for this with more resources. I'm still finding another to solve this. Are you able to load data from json file right?

Comment: Not sure how to calculate the average image size. All 170k records are consuming 148GB on postgres table. When I run the job, the first stage is trying to read the table and shows 170K records in Spark UI. So I think the table with image json is being read. But any further operations like actions are not happening. Even cache() is not working. It is taking a lot of time.

Answer (score -1):

Get the distinct schema from your dataframe and do
`spark.read.json`

Code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import schema_of_json,col

tmp = df.withColumn("schema_t",schema_of_json(col('data'))).drop_duplicates(['schema_t'])

json_schema  = spark.read.json(tmp.select("data").rdd.map(lambda row: row.data)).schema
df_json_data = df.withColumn('json_data', from_json(col('data'), json_schema)).drop('data')
display(df_json_data)
```

Output:

I have tried with more than 200k records.
The reason it taking long time is for interpreting such large number of schemas and standardizing it to one single schema.

So, get only distinct schema records out of 170k and again get schema using `spark.read.json`.

[image]

Comment: tmp = df_code.withColumn("schema_t",schema_of_json(col('data'))).drop_duplicates(['schema_t'])  is failing. Error is: Cannot resolve "schema_of_json(data)" due to data type mismatch: the input json should be a foldable "STRING" expression; however, got "data".;

Comment: The 'data' column in postgres is of json datatype. When read into spark using jdbc it is treated as a string. when applying schema_of_json() on a string datatype is throwing an error. 
I thought of converting this string column to struct and display 1 record. Even this is not working. 

df_code=df_code.withColumn("json_data", F.struct(F.col('data')))
df_code=df_code.drop('data')
display(df_code.limit(1))

The problem seems to be the image files in string representation. 170K records are occupying 148GB in postgres.

Comment: Are you fetching the 200K records from some database? How much data is your data occupying for 200K records?

Comment: I have created this records randomly in databricks itself without image data.

Comment: Give schema while reading data from postgres. On column data give it as `StringType`. Then try above code

Comment: What is the exact code you tried?  Give F.col('data') inside F.schema_of_json().

Comment: "I have created this records randomly in databricks itself without image data" --> This is the problem in my case. without image column my code is also executing. In fact the code is executing fine with few thousand records having image column also.  I have executed the same statements that you sent. The issue is with the image column only. Forget about converting 'data' column to json type I am unable to display the dataframe that is read from postgres. I am unable to execute the repartition() also, on the dataframe after reading the data from the postgres.